# how to load webview in canvasvirtualControl in win2d?

Tags: uwp-xaml, win2d

How to load WebView in CanvasVirtualControl in Win2D ? 
Is there any way to load webView in CanvasVirtualControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas in win2d and the UI controls in UWP are not the same set of drawing systems. `CanvasVirtualControl` cannot be used as a container for `WebView`.

Generally speaking, `CanvasVirtualControl` is used to partially refresh or load resources of uncertain size. The methods in the `CanvasDrawingSession` class show the types of resources that `CanvasVirtualControl` (or `CanvasControl`) supports drawing, and `WebView` as UI control cannot be "draw".

Thanks.